# Eclipse(2019-09) crashes while running SWTBot tests in windows docker

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I am running swtbot tests inside docker with eclipse 2019-09, the tests run fine if I run them from my host with eclipse 2019-09 but when I run them inside the docker I get the following error

```
 !SESSION 2019-11-12 20:17:58.723 ---------------------------------------- 
  -------
 eclipse.buildId=unknown
 java.version=11.0.5
 java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
 BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
 Framework arguments:  -swtbot -suite C:/testrun/NIGHTLY -application 
 org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.junit.headless.swtbottestapplication -product 
 org.eclipse.platform.ide -testApplication 
 C:/tmp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -testPluginName 
 ui.test -className ui.test.collection.BasicTests 
 Command-line arguments:  -swtbot -suite C:/testrun/NIGHTLY -application 
 org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.junit.headless.swtbottestapplication -product 
 org.eclipse.platform.ide -testApplication 
 C:/tmp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -data 
 C:/tmp/eclipse/workspace -testPluginName ui.test -className 
 ui.test.collection.BasicTests -debug -clean 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-11-12 20:18:27.576
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4737)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4626)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4597)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.createHandle(TaskBar.java:75)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.<init>(TaskBar.java:68)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemTaskBar(Display.java:2512)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim.createProgressBar(StandardTrim.java:76)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim.createWidget(StandardTrim.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:998)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:547)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:531)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:687)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.junit.headless.UITestApplication.start(UITestApplication.java:58)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-11-12 20:18:27.654
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:2992)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setCoolBarVisible(WorkbenchWindow.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart.setBarVisibility(ViewIntroAdapterPart.java:222)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart.dispose(ViewIntroAdapterPart.java:151)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:260)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:417)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:998)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:963)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:459)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:160)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:83)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:68)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:186)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:144)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:235)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:133)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:231)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:656)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-11-12 20:18:27.685
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4711)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4626)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4597)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1191)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:687)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$5.changed(WorkbenchWindow.java:865)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:188)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:144)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:235)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:133)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:231)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:656)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

It runs fine in eclipse 2019-03 both on my host and inside the docker.
Can anyone help me what is the issue? Is it the resources provided to eclipse in docker not enough or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Which docker image? There's not enough to go on here.

Comment: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

Comment: @nitind you can see the updated log

Comment: Please show the log from the beginning (starting with `!SESSION` ...).

Comment: what I have tried so far , I copied the eclipse from my docker container to my host and tried to run the tests on the same eclipse and it works on my host machine and running the same tests with the same eclipse inside docker container is crashing eclipse

Comment: The initialization of the class that represents the Windows task bar fails (`TaskBar.<init>`) which only exists on Windows. Does the Windows of the docker image has a (normal) task bar?

Comment: How can I see Does the Windows of the docker image has a (normal) task bar?

Comment: Can you do a _Remote Desktop Connection_? Do you get the same exception when running [this snippet](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet130.java) or just `Display.getSystemTaskBar()`?

Comment: @howlger I don't get the exception by running the snippet

Comment: The log contains unordered (according to the time stamps) items which is not possible. Please delete the log file, reproduce the issue and add this log to your question instead.

Comment: @howlger reproduced the issue and updated the with new log

Comment: This question has been reported by the questioner or by someone else to Eclipse (see [Eclipse bug 552980](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552980)).

Comment: @howlger I reported this question on eclipse forum

Comment: Thanks for reporting it to Eclipse. I just added links which might be helpful. _No more handles_ happens after 10 seconds. It could be that there is actually a resource leak in your code that appears late or not at all, depending on the Windows version (I know from another issue that there are differences between Windows 7 and 10). Could you please provide more information about host and Docker Windows? _"It runs fine in eclipse 2019-03 both on my host and inside the docker."_ contradicts the first sentence, doesn't it?

Comment: I mean If I use target definitions to build eclipse 2019-03 and then run the tests inside the same docker environment, the tests pass, but if I use target definitions to build eclipse 2019-09 and run the tests inside docker it fails by crashing eclipse , the tests don't even run because eclipse crashes immediately

Comment: Docker Windows image is exactly the same for both eclipse 2019-03 and eclipse 2019-09, but tests pass if I run them in eclipse 2019-03 and fails while using eclipse 2019-09

Comment: Using which SWTBot version? Make sure to use [SWTBot 2.8.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.swtbot/reviews/2.8.0-release-review) in Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) as this is part of the 2019-09 release.

Comment: @howlger this is  my swtbot version org.eclipse.swtbot_2.8.0.201906121535

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely you have a resource leak of some description. Have a look at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/sleak.htm utility. Sleak will help you to detect leaks in SWT application code.